# Python cross development platform for beaglebone black

Tags: python, remote-debugging, beagleboneblack

I want to use my pc to debug a Python program running on beaglebone black to control GPIO just like what derek molloy did in this video "http://derekmolloy.ie/beaglebone/setting-up-eclipse-on-the-beaglebone-for-c-development/"
the beagle's cloud9 IDE supports python only for running the code and not debugging

How can i do remote debugging in beagle using python?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The BeagleBone is a computer like an other, with a complete Linux distribution running on it. So every solution working with a remote PC work on it.

For exemple:

- You can directly connect the Beaglebone thru SSH, using editor directly on it (vi(m), nano, emacs), and control execution directly on it using the pdb debugger
- You can edit your file on your computer with the IDE you want and send them thru SFTP, and control execution thru SSH.
- Using an IDE supporting remote debugging like PyCharm or PyDev.

Some pointer for PyDev:
http://pydev.org/manual_adv_remote_debugger.html
http://brianfisher.name/content/remote-debugging-python-eclipse-and-pydev

And for PyCharm:
http://www.jetbrains.com/pycharm/webhelp/remote-debugging.html

(the necessary remote part are the same for the two IDE and come from PyDev)